# gnome-mplayer on Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric) subtitles are on top. Why?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, mplayer

When I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric) gnome-mplayer started to show subtitles at the top of the screen, "toptitles" rather then subtitles.

Anyone know how to configure gnome-mplayer to show the titles at the bottom of the screen?

Edit: To clarify I am referring to the Gnome version, http://code.google.com/p/gnome-mplayer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but I do know how to fix it.

Simply press **a** to toggle subtitle alignment between the top, middle and bottom of your screen.

(MPlayer has a fully configurable, command-driven control layer which allows you to control MPlayer using keyboard, mouse, joystick or remote control (with LIRC). See the −input option for ways to customize it.)

Comment: When I press *b* the aspect ration changes, not the subtitle location.
Could we be discussing different MPlayer? I am referring to the Gnome version, http://code.google.com/p/gnome-mplayer/.